# Mysql use Join as alias on second join

Tags: mysql, join

I need to compare the value from the first Join to the second..

```
SELECT d.* FROM nt_schedule d 
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT schedule_id, locality, key_position 
        FROM nt_schedule_stops 
        WHERE locality = 'Greece') AS getit 
    USING (schedule_id)
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT schedule_id, locality, key_position 
        FROM nt_schedule_stops 
        WHERE locality = 'London' AND !!key_position>getit.key_position!!` `) AS sendit 
    USING (schedule_id)
GROUP BY schedule_id`
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand the question as its currently stated. Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it?

Comment: It's for trips, find from the beginning, the correct destination, but i wanted based on the stops of the trip

Comment: Didn't find the correct answer as, when the inner query of key_position returns multiple rows it returns an error.. Is there any other way? I need to get the value from first JOIN and compare it on the second JOIN...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM nt_schedule d 
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT schedule_id, locality, key_position 
  FROM nt_schedule_stops 
  WHERE locality = 'Greece') AS getit 
ON getit.schedule_id = d.schedule_id
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT schedule_id, locality, key_position 
  FROM nt_schedule_stops 
  WHERE locality = 'London' 
  ) AS sendit 
ON sendit.schedule_id = d.schedule_id
  AND sendit.key_position > getit.key_position
GROUP BY schedule_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution don't know if it's the fastest..

`JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT schedule_id, locality, key_position FROM nt_schedule_stops WHERE locality = 'Greece' AND key_position>(SELECT key_position FROM nt_schedule_stops WHERE locality = 'London'))`